# How does I add a route if the path contains "?"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to map a route that contains "?" in it. But the router is unable to pick it right.

My request path is "http://localhost:3000/?code=38a4d28b0a9244abac8acba6984f2538" and the routes I tried are combinations of,

```
<Route path="/:code" component={Login} /> 
<Route path="/:?code" component={Login} />  
<Route path="//:code" component={Login} /> 
<Route path="/?:code" component={Login} />
```

It would be great if anyone helps me to figure out what's been missing here.

Comment: Using query parameters requires additional setup.  See this example in the docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` to represent `?` as a simple character with no special meaning.

E.g, `"/:\?code"`

Comment: check this https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping#:~:text=To%20use%20a%20special%20character,called%20%E2%80%9Cescaping%20a%20character%E2%80%9D.

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work for you but it is done in the same way